# How to get gif and stickers uri from Gboard

Tags: java, android, gboard

I'm trying to integrate gboard stickers and gifs to my app. But don't know how to get the uri from Gboard. Tried searching on google. But didn't find much docs about it. So need help on how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: See also this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51263655/gboard-keyboard-gif-sticker-integration/55316547#55316547